# LAContext UI on simulator

Tags: ios, swift, ios-simulator, touch-id, lacontext

Does anybody knows what is UI presented on Simulator when you call

```
self._authContext = LAContext()
if self._authContext.canEvaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthentication,
                                           error: &authError)
{
    self._authContext.evaluatePolicy(...
}
```

It asks for iPhone passcode, but in some unusual manner. Whatever you type in leads to success. 
Here is screenshot: 
[image]

On device, if passcode is off you just don't pass *canEvaluatePolicy*

Is there a default UI to setup passcode if iPhone passcode is disabled?

Thanks!

Comment: The simulator doesn't currently support setting a passcode.

Comment: @russbishop, yes, true, question is - what is that, how does it work and how it can be achieved on real device

Comment: I got this UI on simulator too, it only happens on simulator. Quite curious..

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT: I've not found any document from Apple yet, it's my assuming as described below.**

It's fake UI for passcode authentication. On simulator, `authContext.canEvaluatePolicy` always response with `true`. Because of this, calling `authContext.evaluatePolicy` will open this UI above.

If you enable `TouchID` or `FaceID` on simulator, this UI will show up right after TouchID/FaceID fails in 3 times.

FYI: on simulator, you can use TouchID from Hardware > TouchID

[image]

Comment: Can be that. Although, it's still really arguable solution from Apple's side. Any documented descriptions?

Comment: Yes it's still arguable. I dont find any document abt it. Updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will help anyone.. but to trigger/test a success=false condition, you can press "enter" with an empty password string.